# Extract FLV Frame with FFmpeg - Supported Format

Tags: php, ffmpeg, flv

I've searched for many topics through stackoverflow and found many good solutions.
For example, when trying to extract a single frame from a video, i use this code:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg -f image2 -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:01 -y -s picture.png
```

and this will give a picture.png with the first frame of the video.
The problem is, when i try to do the same with **FLV files** i get an error called:

```
[flv @ 0x5597b8] Unsupported video codec (7)
[flv @ 0x5597b8] Unsupported audio codec (a)
[flv @ 0x5597b8] skipping flv packet: type 250, size 758, flags 0
[flv @ 0x5597b8] Could not find codec parameters (Video: 0x0007)
```

So my question is, how can i add support for this? Where should i look?

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Give us your complete command line output.  There are things in there that are important to debugging your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -an -vcodec png -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:01 -y picture.png
```

One thing I noticed is that you have "-s" but no dimension? That option is for resizing so it needs something like "-s 320x240"